# How to enable default controls for <audio> tag via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is how I can include a audio file via html:

```
<audio controls>
  <source  src="audio/was_ist_ist.ogg" />
</audio>
```

Now I want to do the same only using javascript. I have this so far:

```
var audioElement = new Audio("audio/was_ist_ist.ogg");
```

How do I enable the default controls here?

Comment: do you want to create html5 audio tag using javascript for playing song with controls?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697974/dynamically-control-html5-audio-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var au = new Audio("http://...ogg");
au.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(au);
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QKUgX/

Answer (score 1):

```
var audio= new Audio(url);
audio.attr('controls',true).appendTo(selector);
```