# Using jQuery to control audio from image

Tags: javascript

I have three images and each of them have three corresponding songs. I am trying to use jQuery to control `<audio>` from the `<a href>` of the images.

I tried to use [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697974/dynamically-control-html5-audio-with-javascript/12337894#12337894). However, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try including the jQuery library. [jQuery download](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) :)

Comment: thanks .. like I said ... I am very new to this :) ...just trying to do it on self interest ... .looks like I need a bit of googling ...