# how to add background music to a web page with audio toggle?

Tags: javascript, audio, web

I am using bootstrap to build my website and I would like a little bit of flare added to it. I have read some stuff on here but couldn't find exactly what I want.

1. glyphicon-volume-up to right of the navbar-header.
2. music autoplay once site visited
3. volume default to 50%
4. switches between glyphicon-volume-off/glyphicon-volume-up (unmute and mute)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the HTML audio tag

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio
```

You can try it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all). Add the autoplay I have above when you go to the link and refresh.

*Note: You can also use CSS to hide the audio player and [write custom javascript to control the audio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5698024/773263) with your own buttons.*

Comment: Note that if you create the element using JS you don't even have to put it on the DOM tree in order to play the audio.